# How to pinpoint root cause of sporadic XHR error 0 (Network Error)?

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest, aws-api-gateway

I run a SaaS, and we use LogRocket to monitor customers' screens so it's easier to troubleshoot issues when things go wrong. One issue that's been really elusive lately is an "error 0".

All that Sentry logs is "Network Error" which isn't helpful, and a `0` response from an XHR `PATCH` request. Here's what the API calls made from the customer's browser look like in LogRocket:

[image: Screenshot of HTTP calls logged in LogRocket]

This is what I find baffling: there are previous successful calls to the API (AWS API Gateway, by the way). And when I watch the user's screen at the time of that error, there's no kind of interruption such as a page reload, or the user closing the tab, which I think are typical reasons for error 0.

This is totally sporadic. I'm looking for any advice on how to find out what's causing this, because I'm at a loss here. Thanks!

Comment: I believe status code 0 means it was aborted. So that might be due to a timeout or maybe the user's firewall is causing a connection issue.

Comment: I wonder how I can replicate this myself. I'm already catching the error, but it's showing a popup message that we experienced a problem. I think axios reponds with an `undefined` value for `status`, so maybe I can check for that and then alert them that their network connection is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

If it's actually an abort that's causing this, this may help you capture it.

```js
const trigger = document.getElementById("trigger");
const display = document.getElementById("display");
const toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");

const url = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/exchanges?per_page=500";

trigger.addEventListener("click", sendRequest);

async function sendRequest() {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const { signal } = controller;
  
  let timerId;
  
  if (toggle.checked) timerId = setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), 20);
  
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, { signal });
    console.log(response);
    display.innerText = response.status;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    display.innerText = err;
  }  
  
  if (timerId) clearTimeout(timerId);
}
```

```html
<button id="trigger">Start</button>
<label for="toggle">Show abort</label><input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think it's an abort error. The error itself actually says "Network Error." The user didn't abort anything or navigate away from the page (which wouldn't have done anything anyway, since it's a single-page app).